# Картинки сбиваются в кучу

Tags: php, html, jquery, изображения

Если зайти [по адресу](http://sherbinatest.xyz) и обновить страницу, просматривая галерею(именно в Google Chrome), то заметно, как картинки просто сбиваютя в кучу. В чем может быть проблема, подскажите!? 
Картинки распределил по группам с помощью isotop, но проблема не в этом.

Comment: Осень: картинки сбиваются в кучи, птицы сбиваются в стаи.

Comment: Жаль не могу разделить Ваш оптимизм)

Answer (score 2):

Я не уверен, что конкретно Вы имеет ввиду насчет "сбиваются в кучу". У меня в Chrome (Version 45.0.2454.101 m) выглядит все нормально, кроме последнего ряда. В последнем ряду нижние картинки наезжают на предыдущие.

Если об этом, то скорее всего проблема в том, что вся галерея у Вас имеет высоту 930px.
`<div class="works  isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 930px;">`, а картинок столько, что нижний ряд вылезает за эту высоту.

```
<div id="my_video12" ... style="transform: translate3d(942px, 372px, 0px);">

<div id="my_video16" ... style="transform: translate3d(942px, 558px, 0px);">

<div id="my_video20" ... style="transform: translate3d(942px, 744px, 0px);">
```

если Вы не об этом - простите. Я не могу воспроизвести проблему...
Сообщите - удалю ответ

Comment: Попробуйте обновить несколько раз страницу для воспроизведения ошибки.
Все равно, огромное спасибо, что откликнулись)

Comment: да, теперь вижу... все-таки я считаю, что это связано с высотой блока галереи. это явно плагин как-то не так пересчитывает. Т.е. при перезагрузке страницы высота галереи 120px и исходя из этого он размещает картинки. И следовательгно они сбиаются. Попробуйте: 1. принудительно указать высоту блока, скажем 1000 пикселей и попробуйте перезагрузить страгницу несколько раз. 2. убедитесь, что плагин (а именно перераспределение картинок) просиходит после ПОЛНОЙ загрузки страницы, включая картинки. Больше ничем помочь не могу - явно что-то связанное с этим конкретно плагином.

Comment: скорее всего это плагин шалит. 
Не могли бы вы посоветовать подобный по действию, который можно применить в моем случае??

Answer (score 2):

У вас много файлов jquery разных версий, два файла из

```
553 <!-- Filtering imgges --> 
554 <script type="text/javascript" src="files_for_filtering/jquery-1.js"></script> повторяется в строке 547
555 <script type="text/javascript" src="files_for_filtering/jquery.js"></script> повторяется в строке 565
```

Сначала попробуйте сменить название. 
Потом jQuery.noConflict() - вместо $ использовать $jquery.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую и обязательно отпишусь, как получится.